# Excuting assembly file with PCSpim from cmd

Tags: command-prompt, pcspim

If anyone could help me please,
I have PCSpim simulator on my windows 7 PC and I want to load a file and run it from command prompt,
Is it also possible to print -in cmd window- the output shown in PCSpim's console after excution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the HLP file.

```
PCSpim supports a rich command line argument format.  You can control core simulator settings, and specify a file to be loaded automatically.  The command line options available are:

-bare/-asm
-trap/-notrap
-trap_file <file>
-delayed-loads
-delayed-branches
-quiet/-noquiet
-mapped_io/nomapped_io
-file <file> <args>

Note that the -file <file> argument, if specified, must come last.  Anything after the -file <file> option will be considered run-time arguments, and will be saved for the first time the program is executed.
```

So the -file command is what you need to load a file.

Something like this might create a file.txt with the results in:

```
pcspim -file myfile.ext >file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
this command has loaded the file successfully and created the out file
but has never run the input file nor write anything in the second file

Comment: I tried to use something like
pcspim run -file myfile.txt >file.txt
but pcspim gave me this error :"Could not open run for reading"

Comment: `run` is not a supported command according to the list.  Perhaps someone else can help you further as I have no experience with the tool.